# Сессия на поддоменах

Tags: php, laravel, cookie, сессия

Есть 2 проекта расположеных на одном домене, но на разных поддоменах. Например foo.bar.ru и admin.foo.bar.ru. При этом на foo.bar.ru есть поддомены на каждый город (например moskva.foo.bar.ru, sankt-peterburg.foo1.bar.ru). При авторизации на одном из проектов перезаписывается кука сессии и на втором проекте авторизация пропадает. Пишу на PHP, фреймворк Laravel 5.4. На проекте {city}.foo.bar.ru сессия сохраняется на foo.bar.ru, на admin.foo.bar сохраняется на admin.foo.bar.ru. Как решать эту проблему? В какую сторону гуглить?

Comment: Имя сессионной переменной в админке поменяйте.

Comment: @Visman такое простое и очевидное решение.. Спасибо большое, если добавите в ответ - поставлю лучшим ответом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил как написал @Visman - в файле config/session.php есть параметр 'cookie' => 'laravel_session' - нужно просто в одном из проектов поменять значение этого параметра